# How do I make a clipping path around a word?

Tags: path, affinity-designer

How to make a clipping path around a word say a name 'Joshua'. Then I need to take the path 'Joshua' and cut out a pattern I have created. How do I do this?

Comment: So I have linked this photo with a background pattern with the lettering oh baby What I want to do is have the word Joshua with the pattern of the waves inside so it looks like lettering made of a wave pattern  https://www.invitationconsultants.com/product/ICRLP166/Baby-Forecast

Answer (score 2):

The key is to know the layers panel. Here I have a text as my top layer and below it there's a group of colored shapes:

[image]

In the layers panel I right click the writing and select option Mask to Below. The text becomes a clipping mask for the group:

[image]

The group can be replaced by a single shape or a photo. The text can be replaced by any vector shape or pixel pattern.

Mask to Below affects only one layer level downwards.

Warnings:

1) The parts can still be selected via the layers panel individually.It's easy to trash a group or masked shape.

2) Affinity D allows in many cases as well pixel patterns as vector shapes. Many tasks are easiest with mixing both. One should be aware how high pixel resolution is needed in the final usage of the drawing. That cannot be increased later.

Comment: You are a genus thank you I did it!!!! I'm keeping your post to help me later Many thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, but no ingenuity was needed nor available. Unfortunately Affinity Designer hasn't good PDF user's guide. Experienced Illustrator or Inkscape user's find their way with the Help menu, but beginners need more. Watch tutorials . They have a starting link in AD's Help menu, too. If you can spend about $50,- get Affinity Designer Workbook. Consider to click accept button. It's the real way to thank here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to feature persona on your typography? This easy clipping masks educational indicates you the way to create patterned kind in only 4 smooth steps.

**Step 1: Insert Text Elements**

Start via way of means of importing a Shutterstock font as a vector file, or via way of means of typing out a word with the Type Tool from Adobe Illustrator’s font library. Clipping mask may be implemented to surely any vector form or kind inside Illustrator.

**Font Library**

Clipping mask also can be implemented to editable textual content from the Character Palette. With the Type Tool (T), kind out a phrase or word in a ambitious style, like Arial Black at 270 pts. Bold textual content permits the sample or heritage to reveal via whilst making sure legibility to your design. Avoid thinner font patterns while creating a clipping masks. Don’t fear approximately creating a compound path, as Illustrator registers the textual content as a grouped object.

Add Character to Your Text with Patterned Clipping Masks – Type Tool

**Step 2: Search for a Pattern or Background**

With Shutterstock’s Plugin for Creative Cloud, you may navigate and seek via massive choices of styles and backgrounds immediately from the Adobe Illustrator program. The Plugin even has featured collections of styles, backgrounds, textures, and greater to scroll via.

Add Character to Your Text with Patterned Clipping Masks – Adobe Illustrator Plugin

I certified this woodland seamless sample to apply in my design. Seamless designs permit for limitless tiling with out wonderful borders or separations. I endorse a darker sample while the usage of a mild heritage, or vice versa, to assure legibility.

**Step 3: Tile and Duplicate Pattern**

Duplicate your picture via way of means of clicking the picture with the Selection Tool (V) and retaining down the Option and Shift keys whilst click on-dragging the picture. Holding down the Shift key simplifies the tiling system via way of means of aligning the styles flawlessly for a easy appearance.

Add Character to Your Text with Patterned Clipping Masks – Duplicate and Tile Pattern

Select the snap shots and institution them collectively with Command G or Object > Group. Arrange the styles in the back of the textual content via way of means of hitting Shift+Command+[ or with Object > Arrange > Send to Back.

**Step 4: Make Clipping Mask**

With the Selection Tool (V), click on each the heritage and the textual content and hit Command+7 or navigate to Object > Clipping Mask > Make.

Edit the sample or flow the heritage round with Object > Clipping Mask > Edit Contents. To cast off the clipping masks, without a doubt hit Option+Command+7 and delete the heritage layer.

Add Character to Your Text with Patterned Clipping Masks – Make Clipping Mask

Your completed masks have to appearance some thing like this. You can use this on hand device to feature emphasis or persona on your titles and designs in only some steps.